# How do I detect and fill one pixel gaps in image in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to take an image that looks like this: [image]

And make it look more like this:

[image]

My thinking being you could look a line of 3 pixels and if the left and right most pixel green then fill in the cinter one, and do the same but with 3 horizontal pixels. run that 3 or 4 time's and that would take care of most of it.

Comment: apply a closing morphology operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [OpenCV Python library](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) for this kind of operation.

More specifically, you can use [morphological transformations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations), which are available in OpenCV:

> Morphological transformations are some simple operations based on the
> image shape. It is normally performed on binary images. It needs two
> inputs, one is our original image, second one is called structuring
> element or kernel which decides the nature of operation. Two basic
> morphological operators are Erosion and Dilation. Then its variant
> forms like Opening, Closing, Gradient etc also comes into play. We
> will see them one-by-one with help of following image

You could use a [closing](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing) operator, which is:

> Closing is reverse of Opening, Dilation followed by Erosion. It is
> useful in closing small holes inside the foreground objects, or small
> black points on the object.

The result would look something like this:

[image]

And the code would look something like this (you would need to load the image and define a [kernel](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('<path_to_your_image>',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```